# Google Apps Script on edit installable trigger reading populated cell as empty with high user count

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**The Context and Goal:**

I have a source spreadsheet, that has sites listed that my company services as well as a slew of info about the work we do for them and who has done it (unfortunately meaning I can't share this spreadsheet with you, I'd have to make a duplicate and sanitize it of company data, which I'm willing to do if someone is willing to help me ID the issue). I have a few query functions that separate out different work areas like auditing already serviced sites, and data entry for sites that haven't gone live with our service. I take those queried ranges and import them to a separate spreadsheet file where that work gets done so that team members can see what work needs doing. I then, in the work spreadsheet, have a dropdown via data validation that allows team members to apply a predetermined status to a each work item. The installable trigger reads what the edit was (one of the predetermined statuses) and makes edits to the source spreadsheet based on those edits. To identify what work item to go edit the on edit installed trigger grabs the edited row, then the index of a header "Site ID" and reads that cell. That cell is populated by an importrange function from the queried source sheet. The script then opens the source sheet, searches for the Site ID it obtained in the work sheet, and makes updates as appropriate to the status.

**The error:**

This morning everything was running smoothly, until we got 7 or 8 people editing a single sheet. It was working as intended for a time, then completely stopped working. The script would run, however it would not read the Site ID cell. I logged everything, and it was going to the correct cell in the correct sheet, but it was reading a populated cell as empty.

**Attempts to Fix:**

I tried to use SpreadsheetApp.openById() to force the script to re-open the spreadsheet as opposed to using whatever instance the user triggered with an edit. I tried reading other columns and cells, the script read everything as empty that was populated by the IMPORTRANGE function.

**My Guesses:**

I recently updated the script to use the SpreadsheetApp.flush() function to force faster updates than the every minute on IMPORTRANGE. It was working great until this error, but I changed nothing between it reading cells correctly and it reading them as empty.

Also, I'm using a container bound head deployment, not best practice by any means and I'd imagine it could cause some errors, but I'm still learning how to use deployments properly with GAS, and I will eventually be using a webapp as essentially a MVC framework, just not there yet.

**Additional:** [Here is a screenshot of the log and work sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRQ6v.jpg) while I attempted identify what went wrong, one is what it was doing literally minutes before and minutes after this error occurred and the other shows it recording absolutely nothing when checking a cell that most definitely has content in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely related to this [`IssueTracker`](https://issuetracker.google.com/36760530). [`onEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) triggers do have a limitation on how many events they can query at the same time and it's currently 2 events:

[image]

If your sheets is being modified by multiple people at the same time it is most likely the limitation the one that's causing the problem, however if you have identified that even by making changes with one user at a time you still don't get the trigger to properly identify the value from the cell your best option would be to notify this through the [`IssueTracker`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905) and report the problem.

Comment: So this bug, while a huge glaring issue, is not exactly what I'm experiencing. This bug says that the script simply doesn't fire on an edit. Mine is firing, but *not reading the sheet*. Every single function that pulls data from a cell is returning empty. I will report it through the issue tracker you linked, but based on google's responses to others, I am not hopeful.